# How to create Xsd so that the XML with parent and child have same xmlns defined

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have a scenario where we need to have a parent xml tag with a namespace on the tag. The child tag which can repeat n number of times also should have the namespace attibute on it as below. How shall i define it in XSD to enforce the namespace on the child as well.

```
<nfx:Employees xmlns:nfx="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/">
   <Employee xmlns="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/">
   .....
   .....
   </Employee>
   <Employee xmlns="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/">
   .....
   .....
   </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD can control what namespace the elements are in, but it can't constrain the choice of namespace prefix or the whereabouts of namespace declarations. Any schema for which this document is valid:

```
<nfx:Employees xmlns:nfx="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/">
   <Employee xmlns="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/">
   .....
   .....
   </Employee>
   <Employee xmlns="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/">
   .....
   .....
   </Employee>
</Employees>
```

will also allow this document:

```
<nfx:Employees xmlns:nfx="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/">
   <nfx:Employee>
   .....
   .....
   </nfx:Employee>
   <nfx:Employee>
   .....
   .....
   </nfx:Employee>
</Employees>
```

Which is reasonable, because the two documents are considered semantically equivalent, and any receiving application should that accepts one should accept the other.

Answer (score 0):

**This XSD,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:nfx="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/"
           targetNamespace="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/">

  <xs:element name="Employees">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="nfx:Employee" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Employee"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**validates your XML,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfx:Employees xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/ employees.xsd"
               xmlns:nfx="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/">
  <Employee xmlns="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/"/>
  <Employee xmlns="www.example.org/employeeDept/2.0/"/>
</nfx:Employees>
```

**as requested.**